# Shorthand or inline method of initializing members of nested SDL_Rect struct in C, via function

Tags: c, struct, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to improve the readability and overall organization of my project(s) which use SDL2. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong when it comes to initializing members of a nested struct when it comes to SDL_Rect.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
struct gfx {
  SDL_Rect rect;
} gfx;

void example()
{
  gfx.rect = {0,0,1280,720};

  return;
}
```

However, this produces an "Expression Expected" error.

So, what I have been doing, which does work, but just creates a ton of clutter, is this:

```
struct gfx {
  SDL_Rect rect;
} gfx;

void example()
{
  gfx.rect.x = 0;
  gfx.rect.y = 0;
  gfx.rect.w = 1280;
  gfx.rect.h = 720;

  return;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve a shorthand version as shown, or is this just the way it needs to be?

Here is a link to the definition of the SDL_Rect struct:
https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlrect.html

I'm using xCode 12.5.1, writing the project in C, with Clang, C99.

Comment: `gfx.rect = (SDL_Rect){0,0,1280,720};` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *compound literal* syntax to achieve something similar:

```
gfx.rect = (SDL_Rect){0,0,1280,720};
```

This has a little overhead of creating an extra local object of type `SDL_Rect` and copying it into `gfx.rect`.

For reference: [C11 Standard draft, 6.5.2.5 Compound Literals](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and link!! I had read about compound literals, but it clicks when you put it in this context of SDL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
gfx x = {.rect = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 1280, .h = 720}};
```

This seems to work too, but it may result in extra copy

```
SDL_Rect r = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 1280, .h = 720};
gfx y = {.rect = r};
```

most examples [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) initialize struct members by names.